# R: Looping through Command arguments -> VARselect()

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, parameters, time-series

I am trying to check multiple time series on their optimal lag using `VARselect(table$column,lag.max = 10,type="both")` and using different values for `lag.max`.

My advisor told me, I should use a *for loop* and just store the output values to later find the best fitting value for `lag.max`.

This is what I tried so far:

```
for (i in 1:10){
  AIC_list[i]=VARselect(table$column, lag.max = i, type = c("const", "trend", "both", "none"), season = NULL, exogen = NULL) 
}
```

However, I get the error: `Fehler in embed(y, lag) : wrong embedding dimension`.

Does anybody know, how I can build the loop correctly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: What is the `table` dimension?

Comment: It is actually a time series (```xts```) with about 50 entries. The command works perfectly, when I use it outside the loop and entering any parameter in ```lag.max```.

Comment: It works even with `lag.max = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Really difficult to help without any reproducible example!

Could you try this?

```
y <- as.matrix(table$column)

for (i in 1:10) {
  cat("Max Lag:", i)
  embed(y, as.integer(i + 1))
}
```

And see in which lag the error occurs?